# Largest divisor such that two numbers divided by it round to the same value?

Tags: algorithm

I've got an algorithm that can be interpreted as dividing up the number line into an equal number of chunks.  For simplicity, I'll stick with [0,1), it will be divided up like so:

```
0|----|----|----|----|1
```

What I need to do is take a range of numbers [j,k) and find the *largest* number of chunks, N, up to some maximum M, that will divide up the number line so that [j,k) still all fall into the same "bin".  This is trickier than it sounds, as the range can straddle a bin like so:

```
    j|-|k
0|----|----|----|----|1
```

So that you may have to get to quite a low number before the range is entirely contained.  What's more, as the number of bins goes up, the range may move in and out of a single bin, so that there's local minima.

The obvious answer is to start with M bins, and decrease the number until the range falls into a single bin.  However, I'd like to know if there's a faster way than enumerating all possible divisions, as my maximum number can be reasonable large (80 million or so).

Is there a better algorithm for this?

Comment: Do you actually need an exact answer?  Or merely a good heuristic?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the actual best value for N, but it can't over-estimate.  IE: the range has to actually be entirely inside a bin, we can't fudge a little and have it leak out.  So I guess I'd say the algorithm has to be "conservative."

Comment: I gave you a "conservative" heuristic.  Turning it into "find the best answer" would be complicated and would make the running time very long.  A lot better than the naive algorithm, but the heuristic probably gives good enough answers to not bother.

Comment: `M = 80 million` doesn't seem that large, since every choice of `N` can be checked in `O(1)` time. But of course it depends on your actual requirements.

Comment: Your question would be clearer with an example. Could you add one?

Comment: An easy upper bound: n ≤  1/(k-j) because the width of the bins is 1/n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I would like to give another heuristic, which is different from btilly's.

The task is to find integers `m` and `n` such that `m / n <= j < k <= (m + 1) / n`, with `n` as big as possible (but still under `M`).

Intuitively, it is preferable that the fraction `m / n` is close to `j`. This leads to the idea of using [continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

The algorithm that I propose is quite simple:

1. calculate all the continued fractions of `j` using minus signs (so that the fractions are always approching `j` from above), until the denominator exceeds `M`;
2. for each such fraction `m / n`, find the biggest integer `i >= 0` such that `k <= (m * i + 1) / (n * i)` and `n * i <= M`, and replace the fraction `m / n` with `(m * i) / (n * i)`;
3. among all the fractions in 2, find the one with biggest denominator.

The algorithm is not symmetric in `j` and `k`. Hence there is a similar `k`-version, which in general should not give the same answer, so that you can choose the bigger one from the two results.

---

Example: Here I will take btilly's example: `j = 0.6` and `k = 0.65`, but I will take `M = 10`.

I will first go through the `j`-procedure. To calculate the continued fraction expansion of `j`, we compute:

```
  0.6
= 0 + 0.6
= 0 + 1 / (2 - 0.3333)
= 0 + 1 / (2 - 1 / (3 - 0))
```

Since `0.6` is a rational number, the expansion terminates in fintely many steps. The corresponding fractions are:

```
0 = 0 / 1
0 + 1 / 2 = 1 / 2
0 + 1 / (2 - 1 / 3) = 3 / 5
```

Computing the corresponding `i` values in step 2, we replaces the three factions with:

```
0 / 1 = 0 / 1
1 / 2 = 3 / 6
3 / 5 = 6 / 10
```

The biggest denominator is given by `6 / 10`.

---

Continue with the example above, the corresponding `k`-procedure goes as follows:

```
  0.65
= 1 - 0.35
= 1 - 1 / (3 - 0.1429)
= 1 - 1 / (3 - 1 / (7 - 0))
```

Hence the corresponding fractions:

```
1 = 1 / 1
1 - 1 / 3 = 2 / 3
1 - 1 / (3 - 1 / 7) = 13 / 20
```

Passing step 2, we get:

```
1 / 1 = 2 / 2
2 / 3 = 6 / 9
13 / 20 = 0 / 0 (this is because 20 is already bigger than M = 10)
```

The biggest denominator is given by `6 / 9`.

---

EDIT: experimental results.

To my surprise, the algorithm works better than I thought.

I did the following experiment, with the bound `M` ignored (equivalently, one can take `M` big enough).

In every round, I generate a pair `(j, k)` of uniformly distributed random numbers in the inteval `[0, 1)` with `j < k`. If the difference `k - j` is smaller than `1e-4`, I discard this pair, making this round ineffective. Otherwise I calculate the true result `trueN` using naive algorithm, and calculate the heuristic result `heurN` using my algorithm, and add them to statistic data. This goes for 1e6 rounds.

Here is the result:

```
effective round     =  999789
sum of trueN        =  14013312
sum of heurN        =  13907575
correct percentage  =  99.2262 %
average quotient    =  0.999415
```

The `correct percentage` is the percentage of effective rounds such that `trueN` is equal to `heurN`, and the `average quotient` is the average of the quotient `heurN / trueN` for all effective rounds.

Thus the method gives the correct answer in 99%+ cases.

I also did experiments with smaller `M` values, and the results are similar.

Answer (score 2):

The best case for the bin size must be larger than `k-j`.

Consider the number line segments `[0..j]`and `[k..1)`. If we can divide both of the partial segments into parts using the same bin size, we should be able to solve the problem.

So if we consider `gcd((j-0)/(k-j), (1-k)/(k-j))`, (where we use the greatest-integer-function after the division), we should be able to get a good estimate, or the best value. There are corner cases: if `(k-j) > j` or `(k-j) > (1-k)`, the best value is `1` itself.
So a very good estimate should be `min(1, (k-j) * gcd((j-0)/(k-j), (1-k)/(k-j)))`

Comment: Given that the question assumes `0 < j < k < 1`, it's unlikely that j and k will be integers.

Comment: Yes, so I am looking at greatest_integer_function of `(j / (k-j)` and `((1-k)/(k-j))` which will be integers. I have already mentioned it in the braces.

Answer (score 2):

Let's turn this around a bit.

You'd like to find `m, n` as large as you can (though `n < M`) with `m/n` close to but less than `j` and `k <= (m+1)/n`.

All promising candidates will be on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree.  Indeed you'll get a reasonably good answer just walking the Stern-Brocot tree to find the last "large rational" fitting your limit just below `j` whose top is at `k` or above.

There is a complication.  Usually the tree converges quickly.  But sometimes the Stern-Brocot tree has long sequences with very small gaps.  For example the sequence to get to `0.49999999` will include `1/3, 2/5, 3/7, 4/9, ...`  We always fall into those sequences when `a/b < c/d`, then we take the median `(a+c)/(b+d)` and then we walk towards one side, so `(a+i*c)/(b+i*d)`.  If you're clever, then rather than walking the whole sequence you can just do a binary search for the right power of `i` to use.

The trick to that cleverness is to view your traversal as:

1. Start with 2 "equal" fractions.
2. Take their median.  If that exceeds `M` then I'm done.  Else figure out which direction I am going from that.
3. Try powers of 2 in `(a+i*c)/(b+i*d)` until I know what range `i` is in for my range and `M` conditions.
4. Do binary search to find the last `i` that I can use.
5. `(a+i*c)/(b+i*d)` and `(a+i*c+c)/(b+i*d+d)` are my two new equal fractions.  Go back to the first step.

The initial equal fractions are, of course, `0/1` and `1/1`.

This will always find a decent answer in `O(log(M))` operations.  Unfortunately this reasonably good answer is NOT always correct.  Consider the case where `M = 3`, `j=0.6` and `k=0.65`.  In this case the heuristic would stop at `1/2` while the actual best answer is `1/3`.

Another way that it can fail is that it only finds reduced answers.  In the above example if `M` was 4 then it still thinks that the best answer is `1/2` when it is actually `1/4`.  It is easy to handle this by testing whether a multiple of your final answer will work.  (That step will improve your answer a fixed, but reasonably large, fraction of the time.)

Comment: I don't see why reduced fractions are promising candidates. It seems to me that unreduced ones are equally promising. Have you done experiments that measure how good your heuristic is?

Comment: @WhatsUp The point of reduced ones is that there is a convenient data structure that makes them easy to search.  With the note at the end, you can find non-reduced ones from that.

I'm reasonably certain from number theory that around 60% of the time, the best solution will be reduced.  More precisely, `6/pi^2` of the time.  See http://www.mathreference.com/lc-z,cop.html for where that figure comes from.

I have not run experiments.  But my guess is that the answer is always within a factor of 2 of ideal.

Comment: The number `6 / pi^2` is merely the "probability" of two big numbers being prime to each other, which is slightly different from what we have here, since there is no reason for the answers to be equally distributed in any sense (i.e. the answer is not the quotient of two random big numbers).

Comment: To state it more clearly, if we set `M = 4` and assume that `j` and `k` are real numbers uniformly distributed in the inteval `[0, 1)`, then the probability `P(Answer = 1 / 4)` is equal to the probability `P(Answer = 2 / 4)`.

Comment: You are right that I have the probability guess wrong.  That said, if you take `M` out of the problem, can you find me any examples where the heuristic (with the modification at the end to find powers) produces the wrong answer?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. It's true that the `M` value is not natural in this problem. I posted another answer, based on continued fractions, but haven't done any experiments (which I will do now). Could you also implement your algorithm and do some tests?

Comment: I've got kind of a busy day, so no.  However I can say this.  There is no answer the continued fraction idea can find which this can't, however this can find answers that continued fractions won't.  Consider `M` large, `j = 0.5` and `k = 101/201`.  The answer is `n=101` but that won't appear in the continued fraction for `j`.

Comment: I implemented my algorithm. The continued fraction algorithm works surprisingly well. It ALMOST always finds the correct answer. Just for your example, the answer is `n = 400` instead of `n = 101`.

Comment: @WhatsUp Hrm.  I misread the problem.  I thought that `j` couldn't be on the boundary of the range.  But it clearly can. So change `j` to `1000/2001`.

Comment: In that case, both the continued fraction algorithm and the brute force algorithm find `N = 199` as the answer. I'd say it's unlikely that you find an example to beat me like this...

Comment: What are some examples where your algorithm fails?

Comment: Here are some failing examples (the `(j, k)` pair): `(0.287805,
0.296321)`, `(0.34393, 0.368485)`, `(0.3196, 0.325328)`, `(0.0772034, 0.104846)`. I'm now trying to find examples with rational numbers. This is truely an interesting problem.

Comment: A failing example with rational numbers: `(j, k) = (3 / 8, 4 / 9)`.

Comment: Yeah, my heuristic fails on that one as well.  I *could* write a search that always gets the right answer.  I would do it by first doing the continued fraction approach, and THEN searching all of the parts of the Stern-Brocot tree that could beat it.  The "that could beat it" bit is going to be a pretty aggressive filter.